# Hex grid from layer bounds issue

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to use the 'Hex grid from layer bounds" script to reproduce the simple "Mapping density with hexagonal grids" from the Learning GIS book.  When I run the script "as is" I get the error:  Data Source() invalid.

I did stumble upon a pretty good Q&A where there were multiple examples of how to rewrite the script but all of them gave different types of errors:
For example this script:

```
import processing
layer = canvas.layer(0)
cellsize = 1000
input = processing.getobject(layer.name())
centerx = (input.extent().xMinimum() + input.extent().xMaximum()) / 2
centery = (input.extent().yMinimum() + input.extent().yMaximum()) / 2
width = (input.extent().xMaximum() - input.extent().xMinimum())
height = (input.extent().yMaximum() - input.extent().yMinimum())
grid="grid.shp"
processing.runandload("qgis:creategrid", cellsize, cellsize, width, height, centerx, centery, 1, input.crs().authid(), grid)*
```

generates an error:

> name 'canvas' is not defined See log for more details

I'm pretty much a newbie with QGIS.

I'm using QGIS version 2.8 on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: Okay latest update.  Unless I enter a valid name for the file the script will always generate an error.  So the simple fix was to just make sure I run the script and put in a valid path and filename.  The only remaining issue is that the CRS gets changed to (ESPG:4326-WGS 84) instead of the CRS from the popp.shp (ESPG: 2964)....does anyone know why this happens and how i can automate remapping to the correct CRS ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE Cary! You should post your solution as an **Answer** as this can close the question (when you accept it after 2 days of first posting by clicking the faded tick) and help others in similar situations :)

Comment: I **think** your CRS is getting set to default because it's not reading the CRS from a layer (there's no input layer in your `qgis:creategrid` algorithm). What I did with my scripts was define the CRS **before** passing the algorithm such as: `CRS = QgsVectorLayer( layer_path, '', 'ogr' ).crs().authid()`. And then add `CRS` to your algorithm.